# grub rescue prompt

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, grub

Had win7 and ubuntu installed on laptop and inadvertently selected the recovery option in boot menu - exited and now all I get is

```
error: no such partition
grub rescue>
```

set returns:

```
prefix=(hd,0,msdos6)/boot/grub
root=hd0,msdos6
```

ls returns:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd,0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)
```

'normal' not available and I dearly love to not have to stick my oem recovery disc in any other info I can give please ask...

any help would be muchly appreciated.

Comment: Offtopic - not a programming question.

Comment: sorry - meant to post in serverfault... My bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometime grub crash down at the time of Ubuntu installation, it can be installed either by using Ubuntu Desktop CD or Ubuntu server CD. See here the steps to install Grub from Ubuntu Desktop CD[Install Grub in 10 simple steps](http://opensource-sidh.blogspot.com/2011/06/recover-grub-live-ubuntu-cd.html)